# React - how to wait data loading

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using Redux and want to wait the data loading of the parameter get colors to create the variable for the array. But it is not waiting for the data and keeps going giving me undefined

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteTask, setCurrent } from "../../redux/actions/taskActions";
import { getColors } from "../../redux/actions/settingsActions";

import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";

const TaskItem = ({
  setting: { settings, loading },
  task,
  deleteTask,
  setCurrent,
  getColors
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const processDataAsycn = async () => {
      let settings = await getColors();
      return settings;
    };
    processDataAsycn()
      .then(settings => {
        console.log("resolved " + settings);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("rejected " + error);
      });

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  if (loading === true || settings === null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    const onDelete = () => {
      deleteTask(task._id);
      M.toast({ html: "Task deleted" });
    };

    const Notification = color => {
      const priority = task.priority;
      if (priority === "high") {
        return (color = "yellow-text");
      }
      if (priority === "normal") {
        return (color = "yellow-text");
      }
      if (priority === "low") {
        return (color = "yellow-text");
      }
      return color;
    };



    return (
      <li
        className="collection-item card-panel"
        style={{ marginBottom: "30px" }}
      >
        <div>
          <a
            href="#edit-task-modal"
            className={`modal-trigger ${Notification()}`}
            onClick={() => setCurrent(task)}
          >
            {task.task}
          </a>
          <span className="grey-text">
            <br />
            <span className="black-text">
              <Moment format="Do MMMM  YYYY, HH:mm:ss ">{task.date}</Moment>
            </span>
          </span>
          <br />
          <span className="purple-text text-purple">{task.user}</span>
          <a href="#!" className="secondary-content" onClick={onDelete}>
            <i className="material-icons grey-text">delete</i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
};

TaskItem.propTypes = {
  setting: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteTask: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setCurrent: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  setting: state.settings
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteTask, setCurrent, getColors })(
  TaskItem
);
```

but I always get undefined

If I console.log down in the function then I have my array

Looks like is not waiting at all for the data coming from the reducer ( on mongoDB)

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing for React to react to (pun intended). On the top of your function component create a state - `const [settings, setSettings] = useState(<DEFAULT_VALUE>);` and then set it in the `.then()` callback like `setSettings(settings)`

You have a prop coming in as `setting.settings` and you're checking if it's `null`. That seems to be not what you want. Instead listen for the settings in the state I mentioned above.

For this to work you'll have to set the state to a different name or not destructure the `setting` prop to avoid name clash and confusion.

Comment: thanks! I think I got what did you say and i tried with this `const [settingsReady, setSettingsReady] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    getColors().then(setSettingsReady(settings));
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  console.log(settingsReady);
` but it doesn't work

Comment: `then((response) => setSettingsReady(response))` if `response` is an array of the needed data

Comment: Also, I suggest thoroughly going over https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html and other pages there

Comment: Good. :) So did my answer help you?